# Bulk insert of parent/children at the same time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do a `bulk insert` of a pair of parent/child models to MySQL DB tables, but it seems there is no way I could do it with the standard ActiveRecord feature.
So, I tried activerecord-import gem, but it does not support recursive insert for MySQL either...

```
# Book has_many authors / Author belongs to Book
books = []
10000.times do |i| 
  book = Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
  book.author.build(:name => "author #{i}")
  books << book
end
Book.import books, recursive: true # THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

I also tried to achieve it with raw SQL, but I was not unable to find a way to keep the reference of each parent/child because at the time I want to insert the child data, its parent have not had its id yet.
Dose anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: What do you meab by bulk insert? You want the database to make a single insert to all this data or do you all it to handle the inserts by itself, no mater how many queries it dies?

Comment: I want to create just one INSERT statement. Something like INSERT  INTO *** VALUES (***), (***), ......(10000 Times)

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Active record import's recursive flag only works in postgres. I assume you were trying to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this way:

```
books = []
10000.times do |i| 
  book.name = "book #{i}")
  books << book
end
Book.import books // Here it creates Books
```

I am not sure how you can proceed further to create author...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use nested attributes

in Book model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
```

than you can do it in next way

```
books = []
10_000.times do |i| 
  books << { name: "book #{i}", author_attributes: { name: "author_#{i}" }
end

Book.create(books) # it will create all object in single transaction
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said it is a single transaction, but in my understanding it still creates INSERT statements 10000 times. (Please tell me if I am wrong) What I meant by 'bulk insert' is to achieve it with one INSERT statement with bunch of VALUES.